# Show that f(x) = x^ke^ax is a generalized eigenvector of the differentiation operator on the set of differentiable complex functions

Tags: linear-algebra

Given a complex eigenvalue a, I'm asked to show that the function f(x) = x^k e^ax is a generalized eigenvector of the differentiation operator over differentiable complex functions. I'm told to consider (D - a)(x^k e^ax). The problem is that I'm not sure whether I should be using a matrix representation of D or some other method here. I'm not really sure how to get started.

Answer (score 1):

No need to consider the matrix representation.

**Hint:** $f$ is a generalized eigenvector of an operator $M$ associated with eigenvalue $\lambda$ if for some positive integer $j$, we have
$$
(M - \lambda I)^j f = 0
$$
where $I$ denotes the identity operator